# What is the symbol set that Mathematica notebook supports?

Tags: symbols, latex, built-in-symbols

I want to use symbols $\color{#ff0000}{\large\ltimes}$ and $\color{#ff0000}{\large\rtimes}$  in Mathematica notebook for semi-tensor product operator representation.

But it seems Mathematica does not support such special symbols.

Is it the case? or how can I know the complete symbol list supported by Mathematica Notebook and the command `TeXForm`?

Comment: For [named characters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html)

Comment: See also [Special Characters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SpecialCharacters.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are lists of [named characters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html) and [special characters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SpecialCharacters.html) in the documentation.

The allowed TeX commands are in the file

```
/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/UnicodeCharacters.tr
```

You can find them via the command line using the command `grep -o '\\[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*' UnicodeCharacters.tr | sort`, which returns

```
\AA
\ae
\AE
\aleph
\alpha
\amalg
\angle
\approx
\asymp
\backslash
\because
\beta
\beth
\bigcap
\bigcirc
\bigcup
\biguplus
\blacklozenge
\bot
\bullet
\bumpeq
\cap
\cdot
\cdots
\centerdot
\chi
\circ
\circledR
\clubsuit
\cong
\copyright
\cup
\dag
\dagger
\daleth
\dashv
\ddag
\ddagger
\ddots
\delta
\Delta
\diagup
\diamondsuit
\digamma
\div
\doteq
\downarrow
\Downarrow
\ell
\emptyset
\epsilon
\equiv
\eta
\eth
\euro
\exists
\flat
\forall
\frown
\gamma
\Gamma
\ge
\geq
\gets
\gg
\gimel
\gtrsim
\heartsuit
\hslash
\i
\iff
\Im
\imath
\in
\infty
\int
\intop
\iota
\j
\jmath
\kappa
\koppa
\l
\L
\lambda
\Lambda
\land
\langle
\lbrace
\lceil
\ldots
\le
\left
\leftarrow
\Leftarrow
\leftharpoonup
\leftrightarrow
\Leftrightarrow
\leq
\lesssim
\lfloor
\ll
\lnot
\longleftarrow
\Longleftarrow
\longleftrightarrow
\Longleftrightarrow
\longrightarrow
\Longrightarrow
\lor
\lq
\mapsto
\medspace
\mho
\mid
\models
\mp
\mu
\nabla
\natural
\ne
\nearrow
\neg
\negmedspace
\negthickspace
\negthinspace
\neq
\nexists
\ngeq
\ngtr
\ni
\nleq
\nless
\not
\notin
\nprec
\nsim
\nsubseteq
\nsucc
\nsupseteq
\nu
\nwarrow
\o
\O
\odot
\oe
\OE
\oint
\omega
\Omega
\ominus
\oplus
\otimes
\overbrace
\owns
\P
\parallel
\partial
\perp
\perpendicular
\phi
\Phi
\pi
\Pi
\pm
\prec
\preceq
\precsim
\prime
\prod
\propto
\psi
\Psi
\qed
\rangle
\rbrace
\rceil
\Re
\rfloor
\rho
\right
\rightarrow
\Rightarrow
\rightharpoonup
\rq
\rupee
\S
\sampi
\searrow
\setminus
\sharp
\sigma
\Sigma
\sim
\simeq
\smile
\spadesuit
\sqcap
\sqcup
\sqsubset
\sqsubseteq
\sqsupset
\sqsupseteq
\ss
\star
\stigma
\subset
\subseteq
\succ
\succeq
\succsim
\sum
\supset
\supseteq
\surd
\swarrow
\tau
\therefore
\theta
\Theta
\thickspace
\thinspace
\times
\to
\triangle
\triangleleft
\trianglelefteq
\triangleright
\trianglerighteq
\underbrace
\uparrow
\Uparrow
\updownarrow
\Updownarrow
\uplus
\upsilon
\Upsilon
\varepsilon
\varphi
\varpi
\varrho
\varsigma
\vartheta
\vdash
\vdots
\vee
\vert
\Vert
\wedge
\wp
\wr
\xi
\Xi
\yen
\zeta
```